# How to assign a style to SELECTED attribute?

Tags: css, attributes, selected

HTML:

```
<div class="col5">
    <a href="#">DOMINICAN</a><br><br>
    <div class="img"><a href="#"><img src="images/prod01.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="selectransfer">
        <span class="opensans size13"><b>Type of Transfer</b></span>
        <select class="form-control mySelectBoxClass">
            <option>Round Trip</option>
            <option>One Way Arrival</option>
            <option selected>One Way Departure</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to align the "selected" option (Round Trip) to the left, I want to be able to control this attribute (selected).

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, can you add some more clarification on what it is you that you want? im not quite understanding your explanation

Comment: Attributes are not styleable; they are not rendered. Do you mean styling the `option` element with a `selected` attribute? (Note that your text conflicts with your code as regards to which element has that attribute.) What do you mean by aligning to the left? `Option` elements are left-aligned by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly what you want to change (once the options are left-aligned), but you can control this element in this way:

```
option[selected] {
    color: blue;
}
```

And if you want to control the current selected option, you can use this:

```
option:checked {
    color: red;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9njpjdy0/1/

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    #selectransfer {

        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: center;

      }

    .opensans_size13 {
      text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;
      position: absolute;
        }

    .form_control_mySelectBoxClass {
      margin-top: 45px;
      position:relative;
        }

     option[selected] {
     color: red;
        }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="col5">
    <a href="#">DOMINICAN</a><br><br>
    <div class="img"><a href="#"><img src="images/prod01.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="selectransfer">
        <span class="opensans_size13"><b>Type of Transfer</b></span>
        <select class="form_control_mySelectBoxClass">
            <option>Round Trip</option>
            <option>One Way Arrival</option>
            <option selected>One Way Departure</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand 100% what you wanted but: 
there is 2 lines of code for an item you wanted to be controlled
the elements text and selectbox are aligned
I renamed your class names because using barspaces is incorrect (IMO)
Finally, i think classnames should have a short name.
Hope it helps.